# Paypal Adaptive Payment invoice data

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to add item details to show on the paypal invoice but nothing appears.
I use `SetPaymentOptions` with the following values:

```
"payKey" => "$payKey",
"receiverOptions(0).customId" => "11",
"receiverOptions(0).receiver.email" => "email@paypal.com",
"receiverOptions(0).description" => "Invoice Title",
"receiverOptions(0).invoiceData.item(0).name" => "Item name",
"receiverOptions(0).invoiceData.item(0).itemCount" => "1.0",
"receiverOptions(0).invoiceData.item(0).itemPrice" => "20.0",
"receiverOptions(0).invoiceData.item(0).price" => "20.0",
"receiverOptions(0).invoiceData.item(0).identifier" => "111",
"receiverOptions(0).invoiceData.totalTax" => "0.0",
"requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US",
"requestEnvelope.detailLevel" => "ReturnAll"
```

The code is in PHP and I'm using embedded payments.
Does any have any idea why none of the details show on the invoice except for info passed in the paykey request?
Thanks...

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I'd like invoice data to show on the payment authorization page, but I can't find a setting for doing so

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267605/paypal-adaptive-payments-description-field/21015922#21015922

Answer (score 0):

itemCount should be an integer:

```
"receiverOptions(0).invoiceData.item(0).itemCount" => "1",
```

With that change (and a valid `receiver.email`) the `SetPaymentOptions` call is successful.