# PayPal Adaptive Payments - description field

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using paypal adaptive payments for my website. I have different sellers and different products but the problem is that when a user buy something from my website in the payment summary there is the name and surname of the seller instead of the product name!
[image]

I'm looking for a parameter to pass to display the product name instead of my name and the seller's name. I use PHP to redirect to the paypal's page.

Thank you!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463476/paypal-payment-summery-doesnt-show-items-set-by-setpaymentoptions according to answer here there is no way. I hope it's wrong.

Comment: https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment/issues/41 according to this source, items information can be added when using the Embedded flow (the one through popup window or lightbox).

Comment: Can you show the form being passed with PHP?

Comment: It looks like you are using PayPal’s platform (website) for checkout and not integrating it with your website. What advantage does Adaptive Payments have for you over Express Checkout?

Comment: @Luca Pennisi check out my answer and let me know if works..

Answer (score 4):

Here is an official reply from PayPal I got today:

You can display line item details for the Embedded flow only. The Embedded flow uses either a lightbox or a minibrowser for the checkout pages. The item details you set with SetPaymentOptions are only displayed to the customer via this Embedded flow.

Answer (score 4):

With Adaptive Payments you will need to use SetPaymentOptions API Operation in order to modify those fields (line item, business name, etc), you can find all the variables [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/SetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/).

You can find an example here: https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php/blob/master/samples/SetPaymentOptions.php

Line item works with embedded flow only.

Comment: This does not work with the redirect, as mentioned in my answer and elsewhere on the web. You need to use embedded flow for the SetPaymentOptions to actually take effect.

Comment: What is Embedded flow

Comment: @Rohit: Embedded payment flow gives the impression that the payment is handled completely within your website.  
Ref: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/#idb1e25ba9-24fb-4466-bd80-9c9420d010f2