# Adaptive payment control display of payment summary

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, express-checkout

I have setted up adpative payment to transfert money from the paypal account of a user in my website to another subscribed user by following this tutorial : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/

Every thing works fine by using the simple web redirect method.

However I cannot seem to control the information displayed in the left panel "payment summary". It shows always the name of the paypal account which will be credited. However my website user can buy multiple items from the same seller and i would like to display the detail of his cart.

After looking on stack overflow, I found this post : [PayPal Adaptive Payments - description field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267605/paypal-adaptive-payments-description-field) which said this is normal for adaptive payment with web redirection

So how come bandcamp.com is able to do it with express checkout ? I created an artist account, uploaded some files, created a buyer accound. Tried to buy from my artist. My artist paypal account was immediatly credited with the sale. And as you can see if you start the cart flow, the payment summary in paypal show the product detail.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution and it was to not use the adaptive payment library.

You can use the express checkout API and provide a paypal seller account id (email) different from the one making the API call. This configuration allow parallel payment in express checkout (even in redirect mode) and you can controll to which user part of the total amount of the order go.

And with express checkout, controlling the cart detail is very easy.

A link to the documentation : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/