# Paypal chained payments Payment Summary Description

Tags: php, paypal

I'm currently using Paypal Adaptive Payments API to generate a sale where there is a primary receiver and us, the secondary receiver where we take commission. As you can see from the screen shot, the Description Field is Showing the 'personal' name of the account holder of the secondary receiver. Does anyone know how to control the description field in the payment screen? I've checked a few of the answers on here but nothing works for me.

This is the url we are creating (which returns a PayKey):

```
https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay
actionType=CREATE
&clientDetails.applicationId='.$appID.'
&clientDetails.ipAddress='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'
&currencyCode=GBP
&invoiceId='.$booking_id.'
&feesPayer=PRIMARYRECEIVER
&receiverList.receiver(0).amount='.$pay_primary.'
&receiverList.receiver(0).email='.$email_1.'
&receiverList.receiver(0).primary=true
&receiverList.receiver(1).amount='.$commission.'
&receiverList.receiver(1).email='.$email_2.'
&receiverList.receiver(1).primary=false
&requestEnvelope.detailLevel=ReturnAll
&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_GB
&returnUrl='.$pp_return_url.'
&cancelUrl='.$pp_cancel_url.';
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass description in memo variable
e.g

```
https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay
actionType=CREATE
&clientDetails.applicationId='.$appID.'
&clientDetails.ipAddress='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'
&currencyCode=GBP
&invoiceId='.$booking_id.'
&feesPayer=PRIMARYRECEIVER
&receiverList.receiver(0).amount='.$pay_primary.'
&receiverList.receiver(0).email='.$email_1.'
&receiverList.receiver(0).primary=true
&receiverList.receiver(1).amount='.$commission.'
&receiverList.receiver(1).email='.$email_2.'
&receiverList.receiver(1).primary=false
&requestEnvelope.detailLevel=ReturnAll
&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_GB
&returnUrl='.$pp_return_url.'
&cancelUrl='.$pp_cancel_url.'
&memo=What about this payment is;
```

Comment: I have tried this @Mukesh but it doesn't work. I have edited my question with a screen shot to show.

Comment: @TheSumo, this question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267605/paypal-adaptive-payments-description-field

You can refere - https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment/issues/41