# paypal adaptive payments embedded flow example

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using `paypal adaptive payments` for my website. I send request to the `https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay`, then redirect user and process order in my `IPN` return function.

But now i want to add some information about order items. As i learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21015922/5760062), i must use `embedded flow` only. So, i must call `Pay` with `actionType=CREATE`, then call `SetPaymentOptions`...
At this point, i don't understand what i should do now. Should i process `IPN` as i did earlier, or i must make `ExecutePayment` request? And when i must make this `ExecutePayment` request?

Have you some full working example for `Embedded Flow` with `actionType=CREATE` and `ExecutePayment`, preferable for `PHP`.